# Custom connector for Bigquery - Data Studio to cache data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I hope someone from the Google-sphere can help. I have a fairly large query which I am plotting in Data Studio but because of the way BQ is set up, with each loading/filtering of data in DS, the underlying query is run x number of times, where x = nr of plots on DS page.

I am thus looking into the option of writing a custom connector to create a cached data layer between BQ and DS and was hoping/wondering if someone has done something like this prior so I don't re-invent the wheel. The idea comes from Felipe Hoffa, BQ guru, specifically this presentation at the 2018 Google Next conference https://towardsdatascience.com/data-studio-with-bigquery-2018s-best-practices-d2824620cb35

---

Update: screenshot of the BI Engine error message as per @Felipe's question

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Since Felipe and I presented this at Next '18, BigQuery BI engine was introduced. Thus, you can take one of two approaches:

1. Use [BigQuery BI engine](https://cloud.google.com/bi-engine/docs/getting-started-data-studio) for your Data Studio dashboard. This would be a hands off approach where multiple queries won't incur additional cost.
2. Use a custom connector with a custom cache layer. My guide on [Implementing custom cache for your connector with Firebase Realtime Database](https://developers.google.com/datastudio/solution/firebase-cache) explains how you can implement this. The [Chrome UX Connector](https://g.co/chromeuxdash) that we talked about at Next '18 uses this approach. Here's [the code](https://github.com/googledatastudio/community-connectors/tree/master/chrome-ux-report) for this connector.

Comment: Hi Minhaz, Thank you for sharing the code, I was not able to find it. There is too much data for BI Engine to handle, which is why I am looking at other options. I will give the custom connector a try.

Comment: @APlatypus, why is it too much data for BI Engine? Please add more specifics

Comment: Hi Felipe, I'm not sure why, it's the error message I receive. I'll try to add a screenshot to the original question. As far as I understood, the BI Engine should work automatically but for my data source (~400GB) it doesn't seem to work.

(also: I'm very star struck right now chatting with both you and Minhaz :D)